# Upload image to canvas in Node webkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, webkit, node-webkit

I want to upload image to canvas and then run program with node webkit so this  my code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Slicer</title>
    <script>
        var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
   imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
   var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
function handleImage(e){
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(event){
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    }
    img.src = event.target.result;
}
reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);     
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Image Slicer</h1>
    <label>Image File:</label><br/>
   <input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader"/>
    <canvas id="imageCanvas"></canvas>
</body>
 </html>
```

but i get this error when run node webkit :

```
Uncaught node.js Error 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
 at file:///F:/Project/Slicer/html/index.html:8:16
```

** UPDATE **

i forget to wait for load event

```
window.addEventListerner('load', app, false);
```

Comment: You should wait for document.onload and then access DOM elements. Put your script on `document.onload = function { ... }`

Comment: Instead of updating the question with the answer, you should answer your own question in the below answer area and mark it as accepted. this way the question can be properly closed (ref. your other question as well).